# data.table avoid recycling

Tags: r, data.table, recycle

I'm constructing a `data.table` from two (or more) input vectors with different lengths:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(8,9)

dt <- data.table(x = x, y = y)
```

And need the shorter vector(s) to be filled with `NA` rather than recycling their values, resulting in a `data.table` like this:

```
   x  y
1: 1  8
2: 2  9
3: 3 NA
4: 4 NA
```

Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly filling the shorter vector(s) with `NA` before passing them to the `data.table()` constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can use *out of range* indices:

```
library("data.table")

x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(8,9)
n <- max(length(x), length(y))

dt <- data.table(x = x[1:n], y = y[1:n])
# > dt
#    x  y
# 1: 1  8
# 2: 2  9
# 3: 3 NA
# 4: 4 NA
```

Or you can extend `y` by doing (as @Roland recommended in the comment):

```
length(y) <- length(x) <- max(length(x), length(y))
dt <- data.table(x, y)
```

Comment: length(y) <- length(x)

Answer (score 3):

An option is `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
setNames(cbind.fill(x, y, fill = NA), c("x", "y"))
```

---

Or place the `vector`s in a `list` and then pad `NA` at the end based on the maximum length of the `list` elements

```
library(data.table)
lst <- list(x = x, y = y)
as.data.table(lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
#   x  y
#1: 1  8
#2: 2  9
#3: 3 NA
#4: 4 NA
```

Comment: How would you go about this if your list was not a list of vectors but a list of data.frames with an identical number of columns but a varying number of rows each?

Answer (score 3):

The "out of range indices" answer provided by [jogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414452/jogo) can be extended cleanly to in-place assignment using `.N`:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(8,9)
n <- max(length(x), length(y))
dt <- data.table(x = x[1:n], y = y[1:n])

z <- c(6,7)
dt[, z := z[1:.N]]
#    x  y  z
# 1: 1  8  6
# 2: 2  9  7
# 3: 3 NA NA
# 4: 4 NA NA
```